# Remove redundant features using SelectKBest or chi-square or ANOVA with the help of Pipeline?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, feature-selection, chi-squared, tfidfvectorizer

After applying SelectKBest on TfidfVectorizer output, we obtain so many duplicate features in our document-term matrix. I want to remove those duplicate features. I tried some methods to remove those redundant features, however I need to perform so many steps manually as presented below:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer 
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, chi2

text = ["How is your brother? ", 
          "How are your siblings? ", 
          "Who is coming? ", 
          "Who is going? "
         ]
target = [1,1, 0,0]
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': text, 'target': target})
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 5), analyzer = 'char')
sparsedtm = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['text'])

## Selecting best features
k_best = SelectKBest(chi2, k=5)
bestfeat = k_best.fit_transform(sparsedtm, df['target'])
mask = k_best.get_support() #list of booleans
## Filtered features using chi-square
new_features = [] # The list of your K best features
for bool, feature in zip(mask, vectorizer.get_feature_names()):
    if bool:
        new_features.append(feature)
        
newdf = pd.DataFrame(bestfeat.todense(), columns=new_features)
print(newdf)
```

My output looks like below:

```
      r         wh       who        who     who i
0  0.264662  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
1  0.168275  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
2  0.000000  0.117124  0.117124  0.117124  0.117124
3  0.000000  0.123835  0.123835  0.123835  0.123835
```

I want to remove `wh`, `who` , and `who i` from this DTM. In order to remove these redundant features, I found following code from SO:

```
## Removing similar column from a Document Term Matrix
class removeSameCols(object) :
  def __init__(self) :
    pass

  def _delSameCols(self, df) :
    cols = []
    for i in range(df.shape[1]) :
      for j in range(i+1, df.shape[1]) :
        if (df.iloc[:,i].dtype!='O') | (df.iloc[:,j].dtype!='O') :
          if np.array_equal(df.iloc[:,i], df.iloc[:,j]) :
            cols.append(df.columns[j])
    cols = list(set(cols))
    return cols

  def transform(self, x) :
    dat = x.copy()
    lstcols = list(set(dat.columns) - set(self.lstRemCols))
    return dat.loc[:, lstcols]

  def fit(self, x, y=None) :
    dat = x.copy()
    self.lstRemCols = self._delSameCols(dat)
#     print(self.lstRemCols)
    return self

rmCols = Pipeline([('remCols', removeSameCols())])
x_1 = rmCols.fit_transform(newdf)
print(x_1)
```

The output is:

```
      wh         r
0  0.000000  0.264662
1  0.000000  0.168275
2  0.117124  0.000000
3  0.123835  0.000000
```

Now, I want to perform transformation on some other samples like below:

```
vecout = vectorizer.transform(df['text']) ## Using same training samples for transformation 
ch2test = k_best.transform(vecout) 
dftest = pd.DataFrame(ch2test.todense(), columns = new_features) 
x_2 = rmCols.transform(dftest) 
print(x_2)
```

The output is:

```
        wh       r
0   0.000000    0.264662
1   0.000000    0.168275
2   0.117124    0.000000
3   0.123835    0.000000
```

How can I perform all the above steps using `Pipeline` to avoid performing so many intermediate steps manually? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The only obstacle that's obvious to me is that you rely on column names in your removal transformer, and sklearn's transformers output numpy arrays.  It should be relatively easy to modify your transformer to assume numpy arrays throughout, and save the column *indices* that need to be removed, rather than their names.  You could additionally use the sklearn `SelectorMixin` mixin for feature selection classes, to save some boilerplate ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectorMixin.html), but you'll need to peruse some code for it to make sense).

To retrieve the column names though, you'd need to use the tfidf's `get_feature_names`, then subset by the selected columns in your custom transformer.